# When should null properties be ignored on REST API responses?

Tags: json, rest, restful-architecture, api-design

I'm developing a web api for common CRUD operations (entities like Products, Categories) and I want to know pro/cons to suppress null properties and what should I take care choosing to ignore or not ignore these fields.

**Example:**

```
{
    "name": "Product A",
    "description": null
}
```

or

```
{
    "name": "Product A"
}
```

Comment: After ask I found two links but it wasnt conclusive to me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686995
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/285010

Answer (score 2):

If the client send an explict `null` he wants to delete the value for this property. In your first example he wants to delete the `description`  value.

If the client does not send a property at all, he wants to leave the value of the property unchanged. In your second example he wants to leave the value of `description` and all other properties except `name` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

While you are creating new record no issues with both.But while you updating a new record if you pass null for description the record already in the db for description will be deleted, if you don't pass anything the record already in db will exist as it is.