# How to differentiate null value fields from absent fields in jackson library

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

We are consuming an API and the api is providing xml fields. We have to convert xml to json for our consumers. We have a requirement of showing just what we have got as XML and to display only those fields .

1. If fields exists with value present it
2. If fields does not exist don't present it
3. if field exists with null/no value display the field as it is .

What I have seen is general annotations

`@JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)` can be used to exclude values that are empty.I cannot use this because I still want to see the empty fields with null value in json

`@JsonInclude(NON_ABSENT)` can be used to exclude null values and values that are "absent".I cannot use this because I still want to see the empty fields and null fields in json. Same with the `JsonInclude (NON_NULL)`

So my question is if I don't specify any of these properties can I achieve what I want ? In other words if I don't specify any of these is jackson's behavior is to show all the fields that are have the null value on dynamic sense ? My major concern is the dynamic response here . For each requests the fields may be present or not be present . We have to show in the json what exactly we receive in XML

Answer (score 2):

If you want to differentiate `null` value fields from absent fields the most generic method will be using `Map` or `JsonNode` instead of `POJO`. `POJO` class has constant structure, `Map` or `JsonNode` have dynamic - contains only what you actually put there. Let's create a simple app which reads `XML` payload from file and creates `JSON` response:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        Map map = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlFile, Map.class);

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(map);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Now take a look on some examples where we test what `JSON` will be generated for `empty`, `null` and absent nodes.

### Test 0-0

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>
        <c1>Rick</c1>
        <c2>58</c2>
    </c>
</Root>
```

Result `JSON` is:

```
{"a":"A","b":"1","c":{"c1":"Rick","c2":"58"}}
```

### Test 0-1

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <a>A</a>
    <c>
        <c1>Rick</c1>
        <c2/>
    </c>
</Root>
```

Output `JSON`:

```
{"a":"A","c":{"c1":"Rick","c2":null}}
```

### Test 0-2

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <c/>
</Root>
```

Output `JSON`:

```
{"c":null}
```

The biggest problem with this simple and fast solution is we lost type information for primitives. For example, if `b` is `Integer` we should return it in `JSON` as number primitive which does not have quotes: `"` chars around. To solve this problem we should use `POJO` model which allows us to find all required types. Let's create `POJO` model for our example:

```
@JsonFilter("allowedFields")
class Root {
    private String a;
    private Integer b;
    private C c;

    // getters, setters
}

@JsonFilter("allowedFields")
class C {
    private String c1;
    private Integer c2;

    // getters, setters
}
```

We need to change our simple `XML -> Map -> JSON` algorithm to below one:

1. Read JSON as `Map` or `JsonNode`
2. Find all field names
3. Create `FilterProvider` with found names - notice that filter is registered with `allowedFields` name, the same which is used in `@JsonFilter` annotation.
4. Convert `Map` to `POJO` for type coercion.
5. Write `POJO` with filter

Simple app could look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        NodesWalker walker = new NodesWalker();

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        JsonNode root = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlFile, JsonNode.class);
        Set<String> names = walker.findAllNames(root);

        SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        filterProvider.addFilter("allowedFields", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(names));

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);

        Root rootConverted = jsonMapper.convertValue(root, Root.class);
        String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(rootConverted);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}

class NodesWalker {

    public Set<String> findAllNames(JsonNode node) {
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

        LinkedList<JsonNode> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
        nodes.add(node);
        while (nodes.size() > 0) {
            JsonNode first = nodes.removeFirst();
            if (first.isObject()) {
                ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) first;
                objectNode.fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
                    names.add(e.getKey());
                    JsonNode value = e.getValue();
                    if (value.isObject() || value.isArray()) {
                        nodes.add(value);
                    }
                });
            } else if (first.isArray()) {
                ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) first;
                arrayNode.elements().forEachRemaining(e -> {
                    if (e.isObject() || e.isArray()) {
                        nodes.add(e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return names;
    }
}
```

### Test 1-0

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>
        <c1>Rick</c1>
        <c2>58</c2>
    </c>
</Root>
```

Output `JSON`:

```
{"a":"A","b":1,"c":{"c1":"Rick","c2":58}}
```

### Test 1-1

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>
        <c2/>
    </c>
</Root>
```

Output `JSON`:

```
{"b":1,"c":{"c2":null}}
```

### Test 1-2

Input `XML`:

```
<Root>
    <c/>
</Root>
```

Output `JSON`:

```
{"c":null}
```

After all these tests we see that dynamic checking whether field is `null`, `empty` or `absent` is not an easy task. Even so, above 2 solutions work for simple models you should test them for all responses you want to generate. When model is complex and contains many complex annotations such as: `@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes` on `Jackson` side or `@XmlElementWrapper`, `@XmlAnyElement` on `JAXB` side it make this task very hard to implement.

I think the best solution in your example is to use `@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)` which send to client all set fields on `XML` side. `null` and `absent` should be treated on client side identically. Business logic should not rely on the fact field is set to `null` or `absent` in `JSON` payload.

See also:

- [what is the convention in JSON for empty vs. null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619852/what-is-the-convention-in-json-for-empty-vs-null)
- [Representing null in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json)
- [Implement PATCH method with Lombok and MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886852/how-to-deserialize-json-and-distinguish-null-from-the-absence-of-a-value)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information . I agree with the business logic should not depend upon displaying null fields . It is more of the legal and  compliance than business logic .

Comment: @Ags, I understood these arguments. I think, I showed how fluffy is converting `XML` to `JSON` and is not an easy task. We should deeply understand what means `empty` node in `XML` and `empty` node in `JSON`. You can create some rules what to do in case `X`, `Y`, `Z` and try to create custom solution.